# Changing location with $location

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to change the location to the edit page, when the user created a new document,

So I will need to change from, `#/pages/fp_add` to `#/pages/fp_add?id=`

But both of the following is not functioning,

```
$location.path ('/pages/fp_add?id=' + id);
$location.path ('#/pages/fp_add?id=' + id);
```

I guess angular take it as the same page, with or without the parameter?

Any ideas? It doesn't trigger reload

Attached route config,

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/pages/:name', {
    templateUrl: function(urlattr) {
      return 'templates/' + urlattr.name + '.html';
    },
    controller: function($scope, $routeParams, $controller) {
      $controller($routeParams.name, {
        $scope: $scope,
        $routeParams: $routeParams
      });
    }
  }).otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/pages/dashboard'
  });
});
```

Comment: From what I know, it doesn't trigger reload because the two urls have the same url segment, meaning the location path is the same (ignoring the query params). Added just FYI.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try $location.search function

```
$location.path('/pages/fp_add/').search({id: id});
```

**UPDATE:**
I think you should use something like this

```
.when('/pages/:name/:id', {
```

so you can accept **id** as a parameter

Comment: can you share your code ? in a js fiddle or something ?
at least your routing configuration

Comment: see the update ,, I noticed that you didn't diclare id as a parameter in your routing configuration

Comment: I have pages that does not use the id parameter ... I will have to write two `when` statements, any better way?

Comment: do you use the same template and controller ?? in the case of using id or not ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$route.updateParams({ id: id})` to reload the current path with new parameters, even if the url segments are the same. You need to have the $route service as your dependencies though.

Comment: No effect ... injected $route

Comment: It won't change if the current route parameters and the ones to update with are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the right way is to simply execute

> location.href = '#/pages/fp_add?id=' + id

If there's a angular way, let me know